# Best practices for building singletons in node.js

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to build an express app and I need to create some singletons (like db object in Sequelizer).

app.js

```
app.use(...);
app.use(...);
var serviceLocator = { 
    foo: require('foo'),
    bar: require('bar')
}; //object holding singletons.
app.use('/api/todo', new todoRoutes(serviceLocator));
```

todoRoutes.js

```
module.exports = (serviceLocator) => {
   var router = express.Router();  

   router.get('/', (req,res,next) => {
       //use serviceLocator.foo
   });

   router.get('/:id',(req,res,next) => {
       //use serviceLocator.bar
   });
};
```

Is this a good practice?

(I've also read about building singletons using require caching, but I have concerns since in the official docs they say that require "may not" return the same object).

Comment: There's no singletons here. You're generating a new `router` each time you call that function. If it's capturing `serviceLocator` in a closure then as far as it's concerned it's irrelevant if that's a singleton or not.

Comment: `todoRoutes()` as a module is cached however, the Router instance it is returning isn't a Singleton as you're returning a new `Router` with every call call to `new todoRoutes()`. So in this case, the anonymous function returned to `module.exports` is cached as a module but, the `Router` isn't cached and isn't a Singleton.

Comment: yea, but the singletons I want to use are foo and bar, which are registered on    serviceLocator. I don't want the todoRoutes to be singleton. If I create another route, like productRoutes with exports = (serviceLocator) => {}, if I call serviceLocator.foo inside, I want to get the same object I get when I call serviceLocator.foo inside todoRoutes.

Comment: What I am asking is if it's better to hold all my singletons inside an object defined in app.js and pass that object to all objects that need to use singletons (the way I did above), or should I count on using the Module Caching for creating singletons.

Answer (score -1):

How I usually do it looks something like this:

*app.js*

```
const db = require('./path/to/db/singleton');
const sql = require('./path/to/Sequelizer/singleton');

app.use(...);
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  req.db = db;
  next();
});
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  req.sql = sql;
  next();
});
app.use('/api/todo', require('./todoRoutes');
```

*todoRoutes.js*

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', (req,res,next) => {
 console.log(req.db);
});

router.get('/:id',(req,res,next) => {
  console.log(req.sql);
});

module.exports = router;
```

The overall is just to add some middleware that adds it to the req, which is going to go through the pipeline for you. You could namespace it too by adding it to `req.server.<thing>` or something.

You can also do this to generate a request ID by bringing in `uuid` and attaching an ID to every req in another middleware that you can use in your log statements later, that way you can track requests through.

Alternatively, just require those singletons into the todoRoutes.js and use them directly. They're singletons on your server, so I don't see any issue with that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but what I am searching clarifications for is if is it ok to rely on Node.js module caching for singletons or there might be situation when the cache clears and you can end up with a new object?

Comment: That was my "Alternatively" answer, but sorry, I didn't get that clear of a question out of the original post. Yes, when node first starts up it follows the requires creating your module objects and keeps them cached. I've never heard of a time that they accidentally went and I couldn't find anything just now googling to see if anyone else had reported it. Unless you clear it yourself, it'll stay there and can be relied on.